Sufficient Condition on Almost Surely Convergence
Let $f_n \in [0, 1]$ and suppose if we want to show
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = 1
$$
almost surely, is it enough to show
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\{ f_n = 1 \} = 1?
$$
If not, what if we add the assumption that $f_n$ is increasing?
Attempt: I am trying to use Borel-Cantelli to see if this is plausible, but it seems like in the end we will need a rate for the convergence of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\{ f_n = 1 \} = 1$ and this is not given: this leads me to think this is not enough to show a.s. convergence. If not, perhaps there is an easy example showing this is not true, but I am not sure how to find one.

No, it isn't enough. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be Lebesgue measure on the unit interval and $$
f_n = 1 - \chi \left( \frac{n-2^k}{2^k}, \frac{n-2^k + 1}{2^k} \right)$$
for $k\geq 0$ and $2^k \geq n < 2^{k+1}$.
Then your condition holds but this does not converge almost surely. For your question about monotonicity, see:
Monotone increasing sequence of random variable that converge in probability implies convergence almost surely

Thank you for the answer. Could you clarify what is $k$ here and is $f_n$ dependent on $k$ as well? How then, is $f_n$ defined to be only dependent on $n$?

@PartialT woops,  missed part of my definition. Fixed it now.
